# Steam Deck Development - External Device Remote Management

Tags: steam, steamworks-api

I have a Steam Deck preordered and would like to know how to most effectively develop for it. I can't publish a build to Steam without paying a publishing fee. What i would like to do is something like Android Studio, where i can develop and deploy as well as debug my application,  to the Deck when it arrives. I know i read somewhere about some type of server/client that i could set up but i can't find any information on it.

I've reviewed the SteamWorks API to some extent, but came up with nothing.

Anyone know anything that can be done here?

EDIT:: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/steamdeck/devkits/loadgames#3

I found this, but i can't seem to install it. I click the link and allow steam to do its thing, but it just  flashes and goes back to the home page.